# Hexadecimal calculator

Tags: swift, hex, calculator

I´m using swift to make a base converter, it works perfectly when the base of the number is 10 or less, but when I start to input letters it simply doesn't work.
I want to input letters and numbers in the same variable, then take that value as an integer and change the base of it. Any ideas?

```
@IBAction func input9(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let inputNumber = 9

    currentNumber = currentNumber * 10 + inputNumber
    labelText.text = "\(currentNumber)"
}
```

This is how I input numbers, but I have no idea how to do it with letters

Comment: How you expect us to help you without seeing your code?

Comment: Swift supports hexadecimal literals for integers. Just prefix it with `0x`. For example, `let num = 0xABC` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov there is the code

Comment: How do you expect this to work with any base when you've hard-coded the radix to be `10`?

Comment: With that code, you get 9, then 99, then 999, etc. no matter what the user does.

Comment: @RMoyer that works, but if I type for example 0xA, there is any way to input "A" instead of 10?

Comment: @rmaddy yes, that is the point, I want to do the same but with letters for then change the base of that number

Comment: How is that the point? Why are you hardcoding the `9` and ignoring what key the user actually tapped?

Comment: @rmaddy that´s only the example, but I got a button for each digit I want to input

Comment: You collect the digits in a number by interpreting them in base 10. Possible alternatives: collect the digits in a *string* or an *array*. Then you can interpret them later according to the chosen base.